# I can't use css styles on my navbar (using sass)

Tags: css, sass

I'm starting to learn by my own and I tried for the first time to use sass in order to get more clean my code, having everything on sections. So the problem is when I try to give some styles to the navbar, I don't know why when I write code it doesn't apply. Maybe is because I'm not linking correctly or just using bad the sass compiler.

The best option to help me is take a look into my repository where I started to build this project to practice. I really hope could help me because I want to create differents sections like navbar, body, articles, footer using sass and give them styles.

https://github.com/Shylex96/test-portfolio

Edit: After a long search about this issue I see there is a problem with "use" and I have to change rules or something like that, but still don't know.

Comment: I'd look at how you are importing it in your HTML. ``` <!--Title & Logo, CSS link -->
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="#" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/style.css">
 <title>Portfolio - Desarrollador Web</title>``` Also the style.css itself.

Comment: Hi, I just change it from: 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/style.css">

to this:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

but it looks like still doesn't apply

Comment: It's how you're compiling your SASS (which could be anything). If you look in your `styles.css` you have two `@use` statements, which won't be read by the browser. Basically all of your SCSS should be compiling into the style.css file and it's not.

Comment: Yes, I saw the two "@use" erros but it says "Unknown at rule @use css(unknownAtRules). As you said, something its making it doesn't compile.. I will keep taking a look and be patient if someone can tell me what is going on. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY!! I solved it and I'm going to commit what helps me if someone have same issues..

I had to reinstall node.js, install gulp, and change "about_Execution_Policies" from windows.. when I did, I could finally install gulp correctly and then I install again sass. Of course, I just converted all the changes that people told me about into the first ones I had.
I created a new file called gulpfie.js and two more files: .gitignore and .gitattributes

So, If someone need it, can check the changes here: https://github.com/Shylex96/test-portfolio

Comment: By the way. I had to put my style.scss out of the "util" folder

Answer (score 0):

Replace @use with @import in your scss files.

Try updating your \util\style.scss like below:

```
@import '../globals/';
@import '../components/';
```

Save and compile them then copy the resulting css files to dist folder if they weren't copied automatically.

Update the stylesheet link in your index.html file to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/style.css">
```

It should be "dist/style.css" not "/dist/style.css"

Comment: Well, I did everything but still another error when compile: 

Compilation Error
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
        on line 1 of sass/c:\Users\Shylex\Documents\GitHub\test-portfolio\app\scss\util\style.scss
>> @import '../globals/';